# Apache 403 Error with HTTP not with HTTPS

Tags: https, apache2, debian, http-status-code-403, php-5.5

I've got a very strange issue with Apache:

I'm running Apache/2.2.22 + with PHP 5.5.27 (dotdeb.org) under Debian 7.8.

I made an upgrade of PHP, I'm not sure if it's related but I restarted Apache and suddenly all HTTP stuff ceased to work, only HTTPS requests are correctly handled, VirtualHost config of port 80 is no more working correctly, it seems like Apache is not getting the right DocumentRoot (403 on / and file not found for subfolders and files) if I use a HTTP URL (OK for HTTPS stuff).

sites-available/default syntax is OK, suexec and open_basedir paths updates didn't help.

It's not related to IP (it's not fail2ban, checked on other devices)

It's not the permissions or an Apache running user problem (I tried everything).

I even uninstalled (purge) and reinstalled libapache2-mod-php5.

Nothing worked.

Any clue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, it's not PHP, it's the virtualhosts I created using Virtualmin, here's the fix:

- Disable the NameVirtualHost lines in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
- Replace `<VirtualHost XX.XX.XX.XXX:80 [XXXX:XXXX:X:XXXX::]:80>` by `<VirtualHost *:80>` in all /etc/apache2/backup/sites-available/ conf files
- Add NameVirtualHost *:80 at the top of /etc/apache2/sites-available/default file